# C++ code issue? Compiler issue? code block?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am not sure if this is a visual studio problem or if this is a problem with code. If this is posted in the wrong area please let me know and I will change it.

Problem: [Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzPwn.png)I am working on an application. I am getting an LNK2019 error code and an LNK1120 error code when testing my application. I am total stumped on this. personally, I think is a coding problem. However I could be wrong. I am using visual studio 2017 just a fyi.

Program Code:

```
       int main()
       {

         //User Choice for in or out patient.
         cout << "Please choose a Menu option." << endl;
         cout << "1: In-Patient" << endl;
    cout << "2: Out_Patient" << endl;
    cout << "Option:";
    cin >> User_Input;

    //Clear screen
    clearScreen();
    User_Input = validation(User_Input);
    if (User_Input = 1)
    {
        total_Charge = in_patient();
        clearScreen();
        cout << "Total amount charged:" << total_Charge;
    }
    if (User_Input = 2)
    {
        total_Charge = out_patient();
        clearScreen();
        cout << "total amoung charged:" << total_Charge;
    }


}

double validation(double User_in)
{
    bool Validated = false;
    //Validate greater than one
    while (Validated = true)
    {
        if (User_in <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a number greater than zero:";
            cin >> User_in;
            Validated = false;
        }

        if (User_in >= 1)
        {
            Validated = true;
        }


    }
    return User_in;
}

double in_patient()
{
```

Comment: Please edit your code down to a [mcve] and include the full error message.

Comment: `if (User_Input = 1)` -- See anything wrong with this line and lines that look like this?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Currently, I wanna say no.

Comment: The error message <<-- note ***message*** (not just the LNK<code>) tells you exactly what's wrong; what the linker cannot find. That's where you start. _PS: Don't include an image of the error message. Include the actual **text** of the error in your question._

Comment: @Cameron Paul is pointing out that you clearly intend checking if "`User_Input` is equal to 1" but instead what you're doing is "setting `User_Input` to 1". NOTE: You should also get a compiler warning about this common mistake.

Comment: @CraigYoung thank you for explaining this to me. I did realize what he said after i went back and looked at it for about 5 minutes. I have been doing a lot of little challenges like this for about 12 hours straight. I think i can call it quits. I realized I didn't create the function. its a learning process right? anyways, I did get it to work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double validation(double User_in)
{
    while (User_in <= 0)
    {
       cout << "Please enter a number greater than zero:";
       cin >> User_in;
    }
    return User_in;
}
```

You don't need a Boolean also the while statement that you have will run always run but if you change it to `while(Validated == true)` it will never run since you you set `Validated = false`